# мне нужно взять html код но при этом сначала дать ей 10 секунд на загрузку всех скриптов на сайте

Tags: python

Проблемма заключаеться в том что сервер слишком быстро отправляет ответ и по итогу все скрипты на сайте не успевают загрузиться.
есть идея сделать имитацию входа на страницу подождать 15 секунд и попросить сервер отправить уже полностью загруженый код, но как это сделать?

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://1xbit-ua.com/live/football/"

headers= {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
    ,"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text

    ```
````

Comment: селенимум вам в помощь. requests не умеет 'уже полностью загруженый код'..

Comment: что за селенимум? можете дать сылку на видео о нём или статью?

Comment: @FloppyBodya Любая ссылка по поиску на слово selenium в гугле.

Comment: А если попробовать: req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=7, stream=True), то есть включить значение stream и добавить timeout? У меня вроде код загружается. Конечно, не знаю, что вы там ищите, для оценки полноты загрузки.

Comment: @Johan Это вообще про другое. Стриминг нужен для того, чтобы загружать большие данные не одним куском, а по маленьким кусочкам. Всё. Скрипты `requests` всё-равно не будет загружать и тем более исполнять. Он загрузит одну страницу, которую сервер выдаёт в ответ на запрос конкретного `URL`. Он разве что редиректам может следовать. Функции браузера по рендерингу страницы скриптами он не исполняет. Поэтому и нужен `Selenium` - чтобы имитировать работу полноценного движка браузера.

Comment: @CrazyElf, это понятно, я про выполнение скриптов и requests. Возможно понял вопрос слишком буквально. В самой формулировке было написано, что не успевает ))

Comment: @Johan Автор вопроса скорее всего просто не понимает, как это всё работает )